# rijndael function

Tags: php

i'm working at [**rijndael**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) **decryption**, writing inverse function and get stack at InvMixColumns();
So, ref to wiki = http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rijndael_mix_columns -- algorythm for MixColumns (there's also info about inverse MixColumns);

Here my MixColumns():

```
protected static function MixColumns($s, $Nb) {
    $Nb = 4;
    for ($c=0; $c<4; $c++) {
        $a = array(4);  // 'a' is a copy of the current column from 's'
        $b = array(4);  // 'b' is a•{02} in GF(2^8)
        for ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {
            $a[$i] = $s[$i][$c];
            $b[$i] = $s[$i][$c]&0x80 ? $s[$i][$c]<<1 ^ 0x011b : $s[$i][$c]<<1;
            //However, this multiplication is done over GF(2^8). This means that the bytes being 
            //multiplied are treated as polynomials rather than numbers. Thus, a byte "muliplied" 
            //by 3 is that byte XORed with that byte shifted one bit left.

            //If the result has more than 8 bits (128 = 0x80), the extra bits are not simply discarded: instead, 
            //they're cancelled out by XORing the binary 9-bit string 100011011 (0x11b) with the result 
            //(shifted right if necessary). This string stands for the generating polynomial of the 
            //particular version of GF(2^8) used; a similar technique is used in cyclic redundancy checks.
        }
        // b[n] = a•{02} in GF(2^8);
        // a[n] ^ b[n] = a•{03} in GF(2^8);
        $s[0][$c] = $b[0] ^ $b[1] ^ $a[1] ^ $a[2] ^ $a[3]; // 2 * a0 + 3 * a1 + a2 + a3
        $s[1][$c] = $a[0] ^ $b[1] ^ $b[2] ^ $a[2] ^ $a[3]; // a0 * 2 * a1 + 3 * a2 + a3
        $s[2][$c] = $a[0] ^ $a[1] ^ $b[2] ^ $b[3] ^ $a[3]; // a0 + a1 + 2 * a2 + 3 * a3
        $s[3][$c] = $b[0] ^ $a[0] ^ $a[1] ^ $a[2] ^ $b[3]; // 3 * a0 + a1 + a2 + 2 * a3
    }
    return $s;
}
```

I need to find inverseMixColumns();

```
protected static function InvMixColumns($s) {
            //a test...
    /*
        r0 = 14a0 + 9a3 + 13a2 + 11a1
        r1 = 14a1 + 9a0 + 13a3 + 11a2
        r2 = 14a2 + 9a1 + 13a0 + 11a3
        r3 = 14a3 + 9a2 + 13a1 + 11a0
    */
            //$multiplyOf_ -- defined precalculated arrays from wikipedia;
    $t = array();
        $a = array(219, 19, 83, 69); 
        $t[0] = self::$multiplyOf14[$a[0]] ^ self::$multiplyOf9[$a[3]] ^ self::$multiplyOf13[$a[2]] ^ self::$multiplyOf11[$a[1]];
        $t[1] = self::$multiplyOf14[$a[1]] ^ self::$multiplyOf9[$a[0]] ^ self::$multiplyOf13[$a[3]] ^ self::$multiplyOf11[$a[2]];
        $t[2] = self::$multiplyOf14[$a[2]] ^ self::$multiplyOf9[$a[1]] ^ self::$multiplyOf13[$a[0]] ^ self::$multiplyOf11[$a[3]];
        $t[3] = self::$multiplyOf14[$a[3]] ^ self::$multiplyOf9[$a[2]] ^ self::$multiplyOf13[$a[1]] ^ self::$multiplyOf11[$a[0]];
    echo "<br /> t = ";self::array_show($t); 
    //works!
    return $t;
}
//one of $multiplyOf__
 protected static $multiplyOf14 = array(
    0x00,0x0e,0x1c,0x12,0x38,0x36,0x24,0x2a,0x70,0x7e,0x6c,0x62,0x48,0x46,0x54,0x5a,
0xe0,0xee,0xfc,0xf2,0xd8,0xd6,0xc4,0xca,0x90,0x9e,0x8c,0x82,0xa8,0xa6,0xb4,0xba,
0xdb,0xd5,0xc7,0xc9,0xe3,0xed,0xff,0xf1,0xab,0xa5,0xb7,0xb9,0x93,0x9d,0x8f,0x81,
0x3b,0x35,0x27,0x29,0x03,0x0d,0x1f,0x11,0x4b,0x45,0x57,0x59,0x73,0x7d,0x6f,0x61,
0xad,0xa3,0xb1,0xbf,0x95,0x9b,0x89,0x87,0xdd,0xd3,0xc1,0xcf,0xe5,0xeb,0xf9,0xf7,
0x4d,0x43,0x51,0x5f,0x75,0x7b,0x69,0x67,0x3d,0x33,0x21,0x2f,0x05,0x0b,0x19,0x17,
0x76,0x78,0x6a,0x64,0x4e,0x40,0x52,0x5c,0x06,0x08,0x1a,0x14,0x3e,0x30,0x22,0x2c,
0x96,0x98,0x8a,0x84,0xae,0xa0,0xb2,0xbc,0xe6,0xe8,0xfa,0xf4,0xde,0xd0,0xc2,0xcc,
0x41,0x4f,0x5d,0x53,0x79,0x77,0x65,0x6b,0x31,0x3f,0x2d,0x23,0x09,0x07,0x15,0x1b,
0xa1,0xaf,0xbd,0xb3,0x99,0x97,0x85,0x8b,0xd1,0xdf,0xcd,0xc3,0xe9,0xe7,0xf5,0xfb,
0x9a,0x94,0x86,0x88,0xa2,0xac,0xbe,0xb0,0xea,0xe4,0xf6,0xf8,0xd2,0xdc,0xce,0xc0,
0x7a,0x74,0x66,0x68,0x42,0x4c,0x5e,0x50,0x0a,0x04,0x16,0x18,0x32,0x3c,0x2e,0x20,
0xec,0xe2,0xf0,0xfe,0xd4,0xda,0xc8,0xc6,0x9c,0x92,0x80,0x8e,0xa4,0xaa,0xb8,0xb6,
0x0c,0x02,0x10,0x1e,0x34,0x3a,0x28,0x26,0x7c,0x72,0x60,0x6e,0x44,0x4a,0x58,0x56,
0x37,0x39,0x2b,0x25,0x0f,0x01,0x13,0x1d,0x47,0x49,0x5b,0x55,0x7f,0x71,0x63,0x6d,
0xd7,0xd9,0xcb,0xc5,0xef,0xe1,0xf3,0xfd,0xa7,0xa9,0xbb,0xb5,0x9f,0x91,0x83,0x8d
    );
```

Comment: We're not going to write code for you. Show what you've attempted and we can try to help fix it.

Comment: "I need to find" --- this is the community for developers, not for *finders*

Comment: Sorry if i looked cocky. I have no idea how to do that. I'm writing 'Rijndael' for about 20 hours i feel terrible tired, hungry, etc. and have not many time to finish it, that's why i was looking for help.

Comment: Maybe next time, don't wait to start the assignment until the night before it's due ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `InverseMixColumns()`, as seen on the wikipedia page, you have:

```
r0 = 14a0 + 9a3 + 13a2 + 11a1
r1 = 14a1 + 9a0 + 13a3 + 11a2
r2 = 14a2 + 9a1 + 13a0 + 11a3
r3 = 14a3 + 9a2 + 13a1 + 11a0
```

Addition is just the XOR-operator `^`.

For multiplication by 9, 11, 13 and 14, you either define a multiplication function or different lookup tables for multiplication by each of these numbers. You can find the tables on the wikipedia page.

As for the function, just use the fact that `x * y = log( exp(x) + exp(y) )` and lookup tables for logarithm and exponentiation of the same base.

Comment: i.e. i've pre-calculated tables and "r0 = 14a0 + 9a3 + 13a2 + 11a1"; So, 14 * a0 = ?; Dunno how can i use those tables :(

Comment: If you got an array `MultiplesOf14` which stores all 256 multiples of `14` in the order `0 * 14`, `1 * 14`, `2 * 14`, etc., `14 * a0` would become `MultiplesOf14[a0]`

Comment: Would you mind posting your definition of (one of) the arrays?

Comment: Solved, thank you, @Dennis.
The 'test vector' are for MixColumns, not for InvMixColumns; The genius should have written those tables under the InvMixColumns...